# Tricky composite function

Tags: calculus, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f: A\to A$ where $A\in (-1,\infty )$ and $f(x + f(y) + xf(y)) = y+f(x)+yf(x)$ for all $x,y \in A$ and $\frac{f(x)}{x} $ is strictly increasing for all $x \in (-1,0) \cup (0,\infty)$.

Then find $f(x)$.

Your options are:-

(A) $xe^{1+x}$

(B) $xlog_{e}(1+x)$

(C) $x \over 1+x$

(D) infinite

How to approach? Need hints for solving.

Comment: What's the source of this question, please?

Comment: Do you really mean $A \in (-1,\infty)$ ??

Comment: @GerryMyerson It was in a book meant for IIT-JEE(engineering entrance exam in India) preparation.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, that is exactly what was written in the question.

Comment: If that's what's written in the question, then the question is nonsense. It makes $A$ a number, and $f$ a function from the number $A$ to itself. It's hard to answer a question, when the question is nonsense.

Comment: @AmanSharma It is common in JEE questions that the function itself is difficult to deduce. Perhaps they are asking for some property of the function? It would be helpful if you give what the options are.

Comment: @AnanthKamath I was able to deduce that whatever you give as an input the output should be its inverse. But all the options failed on checking this way. I will just edit the question and write the options. Thanks for noticing my question though :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what option $D$ means by "infinite," but you can rule out the three other options right away.

Note that if $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$, then $\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{1+x}$ is decreasing on $(1,\infty)$. Thus $f(x)$ cannot be $\frac{x}{1+x}$.

Now we rule out $f(x)=xe^{1+x}$ and $f(x)=x\ln(1+x)$. Note that by setting $x=0$, the functional equation requires $$f(f(y))=y+f(0)+yf(0).$$
If $f(x)=xe^{1+x}$, then $f(0)=0$, and thus $$f(f(y))=y,$$
which is not true for, say, $y=1$. Similarly one can rule out $f(x)=x\ln(1+x)$. So by process of elimination I would guess D, but that answer really does not make sense to me at all...

Comment: As soon as I get to know the answer, I will come back to you.